# 90’s-ish Virtual Reality Movie

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

I remember watching a movie that was a cartoon with lots of swearing that looked like it was from the 90’s or something but people put on these headsets and entered a virtual world where people could talk to each other and live another life basically. In the real world there was a fat guy with a small gold robot arm, a guy in a pink suit I think and a blond girl. In the virtual world the fat guy was a regular man, the girl was like a Japanese dancer and the guy in the pink suit was a shark. Anyone know what movie that was? I think they were chasing someone at some point.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like "Love is a Download", an episode of the HBO series Spicy City- except in the virtual world the fat guy was a heavyweight champ and the girl was a geisha (some would argue big steps from the respective regular guy and dancer). The shark-guy was the woman's abusive boyfriend outside the VR world.

Comment: Thanks I hadn’t seen it since I was like 5 and it had been bugging me ever since

Comment: Cool series, thanks for sharing!

Comment: thought for a second that’s El Superbeasto …